# how to return object of matching subclass?

Tags: python, parsing, design-patterns

I'm trying to write a method that is supposed to return me an object of a subclass depending on some input data. Let me try to explain

```
class Pet():
    @classmethod
    def parse(cls,data):
         #return Pet() if all else fails
         pass

class BigPet(Pet):
    size = "big"

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls,data):
         #return BigPet() if all subclass parsers fails
         pass        

class SmallPet(Pet):
    size = "small"

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls,data):
         #return SmallPet() if all subclass parsers fails
         pass 

class Cat(SmallPet):
    sound = "maw"

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls,data):
         #return Cat() if all criteria met
         pass 

class Dog(BigPet):
    sound = "woof"

    @classmethod
    def parse(cls,data):
         #return Dog() if all criteria met
         pass
```

Imagine that I would like to make a "parser", such as this:

```
Pet.parse(["big", "woof"])
> returns object of class Dog

Pet.parse(["small", "maw"])
> returns object of class Cat

Pet.parse(["small", "blup"])
> returns object of class SmallPet
```

I have no idea of how to write this in a proper way. Any suggestions? Of course this is a bullshit example. I'd like to apply this on different packets of a communication protocol of some kind.

If i am approaching this in a completely wrong way, please tell me :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not pass the exact class name, look for that in the `globals()` and instantiate that?

```
def parse_pet(class_name, data):
    # will raise a KeyError exception if class_name doesn't exist
    cls = globals()[class_name]
    return cls(data)

cat = parse_pet('Cat', 'meow')
big_pet = parse_pet('BigPet', 'woof')
```

Comment: Because I could as well write:
cat = Cat(args)
big_pet = BigPet(args)

I am looking for a class method in some root class, which calls the same overridden function in all its children to see if a better match is found there.

Comment: You counter-proposal would require an awfully big, developer-maintained map between strings and classes and your second proposal doesn't seem to have any obvious rationale or advantage. Most serializers map strings directly to class names or types.

Comment: Perhaps, but your proposal suggests that  I keep a map on paper, manually inspect each packet and return an object of the type I like. There must be another way

Comment: In fact I generate all different packets of some protocol. I have a base class packet, and bunch of intermediate classes adding detail every time, to finally end up with one class per packet type. Generation is trivial. I would like to use the same structure to parse incoming data.

And i would like Packet.parse("incoming data") to return an obj of Packet subclass Ack(), if that is the case.

Obviously any data can be a packet. So if all else fails, an obj of class Packet is returned. If some protocol identifier matches, i can do better and return an obj of class MyProtocol. Etc ...

Comment: No, my proposal is that you blindly try to map any incoming data to an existing class name and handle the exception if it doesn't exist. This is how all serialization works. If I edit a Photoshop file and add invalid characters to it, Photoshop will try to open it but fail if it encounters something it deems invalid.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense now. I'll try that

Comment: Perhaps you've abstracted your question too much, since it doesn't seem to illustrate your requirements very clearly when it comes to how you're planning to deal with packets. Regardless, I'd still say you should try to map the packets to class names as closely as possible.